# How to differentiate between opening an iOS app after fresh install and after an update

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am implementing a feature to iOS app that have different behavior if the app is fresh installed or just updated from an older version

i.e. I need to show an alert to users who first open the app after updating it from an older version and not to show this alert to new users who installed a fresh copy of the latest version of the app

I used to know this information in other apps I did before by storing the version number and the build number into `NSUserDefault` but the case now is that I don't have this code in place.

So to do this I'll need to submit an extra build to Apple store, and even then I can only detect updating the app starting from this version but updating from older version to the next one will be counted as new install not update

So is the is any way I can get this information from the iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Is there other NSUserDefaults your users have in your previous version that are mandatory for the app? You can use that as a workaround. If those exist, put up the alert, and add a new NSUserDefault key that the alert has been seen and not to display again. Otherwise set the setting to turn off the alert indefinitely.

But it's important to think of future releases going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Detect installation.
NSString *currentVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString *currentBuild = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSString *versionOfLastVersionRun = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"VersionOfLastVersionRun"];
NSString *versionOfLastBuildRun = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"VersionOfLastBuildRun"];

//Copy all the bundle JSON
if (versionOfLastVersionRun == nil) {
    //Do something on first installation
} else if (![versionOfLastVersionRun isEqual:currentVersion]) {
    //Do something if there is a new version
} else if (![versionOfLastBuildRun isEqual:currentBuild]) {
    //Do something if there is a new build
}

//Save values.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentVersion forKey:@"VersionOfLastVersionRun"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentBuild forKey:@"VersionOfLastBuildRun"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I hope this helps.

Happy coding.

**EDIT**

I have not sean that the question is marked as Swift, but I'm going to left this answer for someone in the future that maybe find this helpful.

Comment: This question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c": please provide your answer in Swift. Thanks.

Comment: @EricD Sorry I didn't saw the label, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: I don't need help, I'm not the OP. I was just telling you that your answer is off-topic because it's in the wrong language. :) You can always delete your answer - or ask the OP if they're ok with an answer in Objective-C (and if it's the case, they can edit their question to explicitly state this).

Comment: That what I already explained in the question, using this solution you will consider updating from older versions as new install not update